# Vim Remove/Insert using Visual block select after a colon

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I've got this piece of code:

```
fill_in "Name",with: "John"
fill_in "Email",with: "user@example.com"
fill_in "Password",with: "supersafe"
```

I would like to replace everything that is written after `:` with `user.`, so I can complete the code by just adding `name`, `email` and `password`, accordingly after the `user.`.

```
fill_in "Name",with: user.name
fill_in "Email",with: user.email
fill_in "Password",with: user.password
```

Moreover, a way (maybe a vim plugin?) to navigate from one line of the visual block selected to the other would be just optimal of course, though not the main point here.

A simpler option would be to instead of replacing it with `user.`, just delete it with `d$`; however the selection issue still stands.

I tried it with normal `Ctrl-V` selection but since the `:` characters are placed in different columns of each line, I don't have the desired behaviour.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, if (like me) you prefer to work with the commands that you'd use to edit manually, instead of entering crazy regular expression land:

> #### `:g/with:/norm yi"$"_ca"␣user.`<kbd>C-r</kbd>`"`<kbd>`Esc`</kbd>`v```.u`

1. `g:/with:/` (apply to all lines containing "with:" (this is actually optional if the buffer contains no other lines)
2. `norm` the following "keys" in normal mode:

   - `yi"` *<sub>(yank the first quoted value)</sub>*
   - `$` *<sub>(move to end of line...)</sub>*
   - `"_ca"` *<sub>(change the quoted text)</sub>* `␣user.` *<sub>(starting with `user.`)</sub>* <kbd>C-r</kbd>`"` *<sub>(and the originally yanked text)</sub>* <kbd>`Esc`</kbd> *<sub>(done)</sub>*
   - `v```.u` *<sub>(lowercase the pasted bit)</sub>*

It's probably a matter of taste, but it works very well for me.

**Complicated?** Here's a trick: What I ***actually*** did, is perform the edit on one line (recording a macro with <kbd>qq</kbd>...<kbd>q</kbd>), then

```
:%norm @q
```

applies it to all lines

Demo: *(note it still used `gu```.`instead of`v``` \``.u ```)*:

[image]

Comment: I almost always think regex before macro for some reason.

Comment: @FDinoff Because you're a programmer, likely? :/ Me too, but I find myself staying out of regex's way since I have learned to appreciate the full power of `:g`, `:v`, `:%norm`, `:t`, `:m` and friends. I mean, `:%>|%y +|undo` beats the crap out of _indenting, yanking to the X clipboard and undoing the whole buffer_ manually (guess what I need that for)

Comment: I must say I was pleasantly surprised by the position of `'.`. I did not realize it behaved differently due to the use of `<c-r>`. I learned something new today. Thank you. One possible flaw: ``gu`.`` will not lowercase the last character. Easily fixed with something like `guiw`.

Comment: @PeterRincker Excellent spot. I fixed it (not with `iw` because it assumes too much. Instead I now used `v`\``.u`)

Comment: fantastic reply! I will have to learn about macros and other details. I will learn a lot from this one too!

Answer (score 3):

This would work just highlight the lines you want it to run on.

Non magic regex

```
s/.\{-}"\(.\{-}\)".\{-}:\zs.*/ user.\L\1/g
```

very magic regex

```
s/\v.{-}"(.{-})".{-}:\zs.*/ user.\L\1/g
```

This captures the thing in quotes. Since this uses `\zs` the match start after the colon. So everything after the colon is replaced with `user.` and the lowercase version of whatever was  in quotes. `\L` turns the string after to the lowercase version of it.

Comment: wow that works like a charm. Although I was looking for a simpler way to achieve that. I believe some editors like TextMate and SublimeText can block-select after a certain character. Thank you anyhow, I will learn from that command!

Comment: Nice. It could do with a `\m`, \v` or `\V` to assert the `magic`-ness. I provided my own regex-less answer (based on motion commands and repeat commands) for good measure :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, another macro:

```
qq     start recording in register q
0      go to the first column
yi"    yank the content of the first pair of quotes
f";    jump to the next pair of quotes
"_c$   change until the end of line, sending the previous text to the black hole register
user.  insert user.
<C-r>" insert the content of the default register
<Esc>  exit insert mode
guiw   change the case of the word under the cursor
q      stop recording
```

I'm sure there are dozens of ways to do obtain the same result.

Comment: `guiw` _assumes_ that the thing inside first "" is a single word (for lowercasing). Just saying.

Comment: @sehe, you are right. Would `guT.` be generic enough? And now that I think about it, `f";` could be replaced by `W` in the given sample.

Comment: I think `f";` expresses intent more clearly, and is less brittle. I just fixed a problem spotted by a commenter using `v`\``.u` in my answer :/